# Detect errors in a WORD file while converting to PDF file through PHP COM

Tags: php, windows, com, ms-word, rtf

I am using the [**COM**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) extension of PHP to convert a Word document (or an RTF file) to PDF file with PHP.
This is my sample code:

```
<?php
$word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
$word->Visible = 0;
$word->DisplayAlerts = 0;  
$word->Documents->Open('C:\docs\test.rtf');  
$word->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\docs\test.pdf', 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
$word->Quit(false);
unset($word);
?>
```

But for some of the documents (damaged or containing errors), the conversion does not happen and the execution continues till max_execution_time, and does not show any error, except a blank screen.

Normally, when i open the corresponding RTF file on my system, it displays a warning as below:

[image]

My question is, can i identify whether the RTF file has an error in it from my PHP code? (I can find it when i open the file manually, and it displays a warning box as above)

NOTE: When i run my php code in windows localhost, i can see a new task being created in my Task Manager, with the name: '**Show Repairs**' and when i switch to it, it is the same as the above image. And when i kill it, the php code converts the RTF to PDF file instantly.

Comment: So i want to know, is there a way to disable warnings or ignore the dialogs via php code. I already specified: DisplayAlerts as 0, but i guess i need another setting.

Comment: The fix is to prevent the "Show Repairs" dialog box from appearing (when php tries to convert a damaged document). **[Reference Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903740)**. But that does not seem to be the recommended option.